# Google Cloud Messaging restrictions

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-messaging

I've just added GCM pushes to my Android app, and developed Rails backend for it. When I tested it the system worked good. Later I tried to send pushes from my server again but my app got nothing; after 30 minutes it got 3 notifications at the same time. What's the trouble?  Does GCM have some restrictions? For example, count of notifications per houror something else. Is it possible to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just a bug of GCM they got the same thing.